# Regarding the use of the < operator in Shell

Tags: powershell

```
PS C:\Users\Tim\desktop\Practice> cmd \c python .\teststreams.py < input.txt
```

returns the following error message:

`The '<' operator is reserved for future use.`

Is there any way around this in Powershell or am I going to have to resort to DOS?
It does work in DOS, though I would like to stay with Powershell

Comment: This is a Powershell issue, not a Python issue.

Comment: good to go @MartijnPieters ill go elsewhere

Comment: @Wooble the example you gave didn't include python before the file, which I tried. It didn't even occur to me until now that python was needed before the file as well

Answer (score 1):

What are you even trying there by passing `\c` as an argument to `cmd`? Not that you need `cmd` at all:

```
Get-Content input.txt | python teststreams.py
```

Answer (score 0):

`PS C:\Users\Tim\desktop\Practice> Get-Content input.txt |python .\teststreams.py`, 
I didn't add the python before, I initially used `PS C:\Users\Tim\desktop\Practice> Get-Content input.txt | .\teststreams.py` and it didn't work